# How to wrap words with "<" and ">" with a loop?

Tags: loops, text, emacs

My textfile looks like this:

```
laudare
at
dominus
serere1
enim
```

And what I need is:

```
<laudare>
<at>
<dominus>
<serere1>
<enim>
```

I'm a beginner in programming an I tried to write this elisp function:

```
(defun insert-angle-brackets-at-word () 
  "Insert angle brackets, i.e. <WORD>."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (insert "\<")
  (forward-word)
  (insert "\>")
  (forward-line 1))
```

This function obviously "works" only for the first word in the textfile. How should the function look like to work for the entire textfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to loop, you can use `replace-string` to replace all the newlines:

```
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (insert "<")
  (replace-string "\n" ">\n<")
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (insert ">")
```

Comment: @DanRu: "Thank you" on StackOverflow = upvote/accept :-)

Comment: You can easily make it work with regions too.  Just wrap it in `(save-restriction (narrow-to-region b e) ... )`

Answer (score 0):

As someone else said, you can use find and replace, however you may also want to take a look at [macros](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1jJS_aibPA) and [multiple cursors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNa3axo40qM). They can be a simpler way of achieving this kind of behaviour in the future, depending on what you want to do.

With a Macro, you could press `f3` to begin recording a Macro, then go to the beginning of the line with `home`, delete the opening `<` with `delete`, go forward one word with `M-f`, delete the closing `>` with `delete` and  then go down and to the beginning of the next line using `down` and then `home`. Finish the Macro with `f4`.

So, to recap: `f3`, `home`, `delete`, `M-f`, `delete`, `down`, `home`, `f4`.

You can then call the macro (also using `f4`) and it will re-execute that series of commands from the current point position. Provide a prefix argument with `C-u` to get multiple executions.

Multiple cursors works similarly, but you execute the operations over multiple points simultaneously. It's not a package I've experimented with but it uses the same principle.

Comment: You might want to give a specific example, for the case in the question.